# Cordova PushPlugin - Can't receive GCM notification on android if app is not running

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, notifications, push

This is my first message here.
I'm using Cordova to develop an web application and I would like to receive Push Notification under Android using GCM.

I tried the this plugin : https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
I tried the example provided and it's working fine when the app is running : 
- Received notification is shown inside the app if it's running in foreground
- Received notification is shown inside the android notification bar is the app is running in background.

**My problem**: if I restart my smartphone, or if the app is not running, then I cannot receive any notification.
Is there something special to do to display notification in the android notification bar when the application is not running or after the phone restarts ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

there should be a broadcast receiver in your app for invoke notification service or you can use this
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: Well... I used this already : https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin and I have the problem with this plugin, with the provided example.

Comment: Finally I tried it again from scratch and I used the automatic installation of the plugin using plugman instead of the manual installation.
Now it's working fine. I don't know what was wrong yesterday.

Now I have another problem... I cannot stop receiving notification, even after a call to unregister. But that's an another problem :).

Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: When the app is register for a push notification we can save its unique push id for that particular device. so when you want to unregister that app for a pushnotification you need to remove that id from server to send the pushnotification to that particular device.